# How to delete a project in cplex optimization studio?

Tags: cplex

How to delete a project in cplex optimization studio?  I've deleted the project files to the extent that they don't show up in search but when I try to create a new project with the same name it says such a project already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Delete folder corresponding to your project in following directory "workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects"